# on the Y/N I would like a lowercase y to be able to respond exactly how an uppercase Y would

Tags: python

When it asks the user if they would like to "run the coin toss simulation(Y/N)" I want the user to be able to input a lowercase y as well as an uppercase Y and having them both do the same thing. What is happening when I put a lowercase y is that it gives me the goodbye message as if the user inputted N

the areas that deal with this are on lines 7-9 and 32-34 any help is greatly appreciated, thanks all

```
import random
def main():
    name = input("Hello user, please enter your name: ")
    print("Hello", name , "This program runs a coin toss simulation")
    yn = input("Would you like to run the coin toss simulation?(Y/N): ")
    if yn != 'Y':
        print("Ok have a nice day!")
        return

    while True:
        heads = tails = 0
        while True:
            count = int(input("Enter the amount of times you would like the coin to flip: "))
            if count <= 0: 
                print("Silly rabbit, that won't work")
            else:
                break

        while tails + heads < count:
            coin = random.randint(1, 2)
            if coin ==1:
                heads = heads + 1
            else:
                tails = tails + 1

        print("you flipped", count , "time(s)")
        print("you flipped heads", heads , "time(s)")
        print("you flipped tails", tails , "time(s)")

        yn = input("Would you like to run another coin toss simulation?(Y/N): ")
        if yn != 'Y':
            print("Ok have a nice day!")
            return
```

main()

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.lower()` method:

```
if yn.lower() != 'y'
```

You could also use `.upper()`:

```
if yn.upper() != 'Y'
```

However, programmers are lazy and like to avoid hitting the Shift key as much as possible, hence the ongoing popularity of `.lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

Give them a few options

```
if yn.lower() not in ('y', 'yes'):
    ...
```